# I need help converting VB.Net code block to C# (Setting Property with DataTable Value)

Tags: c#

I am writing my first C# application, which in this case is just a "learning exercise" This example is a simplified block of code that I have used many times in VB.Net so I know that it works correctly. This is what the VB code looks like.

```
Public Class User
    Private Const CN_LoginId As String = "Login"
    Private Const CN_Password As String = "Password"
    Private _password As String

    Public Property Password() As String
        Get
            Return _password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Function Create(ByVal Login As String) As User
        Dim usr = New User()

        Using dt As DataTable = DAC.ExecuteDataTable("usp_PasswordSelect", _
            DAC.Parameter(CN_LoginId, Login))
            With dt.Rows(0)
                usr.Password = CStr(.Item(CN_Password))
            End With
        End Using

        Return usr
    End Function
End Class
```

So in C# I have tried converting it by hand and by using Telerik's online conversion utility, which is what I am posting below because I am assuming that it is closer to the right answer then what I did myself.

```
public class User
{
    private const string CN_LoginId = "Login";
    private const string CN_Password = "Password";
    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; }
    }

    public static User Create(string Login)
    {
        object usr = new User();

        using (DataTable dt = DAC.ExecuteDataTable("usp_PasswordSelect", 
            DAC.Parameter(CN_LoginId, Login)))
        {
            {
                usr.Password = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(CN_Password));
            }
        }

        return usr;
    }

}
```

The first error I get is on this line usr.Password = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(CN_Password));. The error is "Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Password' and no extension method 'Password' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

At this point I am assuming the second error will go away when I fix the first one. So my question is how do I correctly set the property for this Object using the DataTable in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
public class User
{
    private const string CN_LoginId = "Login";
    private const string CN_Password = "Password";

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public static User Create(string Login)
    {
        User usr = new User();
        using (DataTable dt = DAC.ExecuteDataTable("usp_PasswordSelect", 
            DAC.Parameter(CN_LoginId, Login)))
            {
                usr.Password = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_Password]);
            }
        return usr;
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. C# accesses arrays using square brackets, not parens.  So `Rows(0)` isn't correct - it should be `Rows[0]`.
2. I agree with Bernard that you should declare the `User` object as a `User`, and not as  an `object`.  You'll lose all visibility into it's properties.  You can also use `var`, but if you're learning C#, you may be better off explicitly declaring your variable types.  It can make for duplicate declarations (e.g. `User u = new User()`) but at least you'll see clearly what types your variables are.
3. You don't need to access array items using `Item`...just get it as an element in the row element you're working with.  That's why I have the double array for `dt.Rows[0][CN_Password]`.  Again, C# uses square brackets, not parens for accessing array elements.
4. This is just a style thing, but I removed your `_password` field and just used an automatic property for `Password`.  I didn't see `_password` being used in your code and thought it would just clutter things up.  Automatic properties have a backing field automatically created by the compiler, so you don't have to keep track of the variable and the property.  If you're using a lot of properties, this can be a big time saver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type of user (in your code user is an object that is at runtime a USer, but not at compiletime). You can do the following:

```
var user = new User();
```

or

```
User user = new User();
```

In addition to the comments.
As Jonathan Dickinson correctly says ,

```
user.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"];
```

should do it since this is an indexer.

Comment: That is how I started (my own conversion) but I had trouble with this (my original version) user.Password = dt.Rows[0]("Password"); It says that a Method Name is Expected. I couldn't get it figured out, which is why I tried the conversion utility.

Comment: In addition, before converting, you may want to make sure Option Strict is turned On to avoid implicit type casting to prepare for your conversion.

Comment: @BukHix in other words, taking this and [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166443/i-need-help-converting-vb-net-code-block-to-c-setting-property-with-datatable-v/7166685#7166685) gives you the answer. `user.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"]`